# OpenGL multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, boost-asio

Ok I am trying to switch my Game Engine to multithreading. I have done the research on how to make it work to use OpenGL in multithreaded application. I have no problem with rendering or switching contexts. Let my piece of code explain the problem :) :

```
for (it = (*mIt).Renderables.begin(); it != (*mIt).Renderables.end(); it++)
{
    //Set State Modeling matrix
    CORE_RENDERER->state.ModelMatrix = (*it).matrix;
    CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveSubmesh = (*it).submesh;

    //Internal Model Uniforms
    THREAD_POOL->service.post([&]
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveShaderProgram->InternalModelUniforms.size(); i++)
        {
            CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveShaderProgram->InternalModelUniforms[i]->Set( CORE_RENDERER->state.ModelMatrix);
        }

        CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveSubmesh->_Render();
    });

    //Sleep(10);
}
```

I'll quickly explain what are the elements in the code to make my problem more clear. Renderables is a simple std::vector of elements with _Render() function which works perfectly. CORE_RENDERER->state is a struct holding information about current render state such as current material properties as well as current submesh ModelMatrix. So Matrix and Submesh are stored to state struct (I KNOW THIS IS SLOW, I'll probably change that in time :) ) The next piece of code is sent to THREAD_POOL->service which is actually boost::asio::io_service and has only one thread so it acts like a queue of rendering commands. The idea is that the main thread provides information about what to render and do frustum culling and other tests while an auxilary thread does actual rendering. This works fine, except there is a slight problem:

The code that is sent to thread pool starts to execute, but before all InternalModelUniforms are set and submesh is rendered the next iteration of Renderables is executed and both ModelMatrix and ActiveSubmesh are changed. The program doesn't crash but both informations change and some meshes are rendered some matrices are right others not which results in flickering image. Objects apear on frame and the next frame they are gone. The problem is only fixed if I enable that Sleep(10) function which makes sure that the code is executed before next iteration which obviously kills the idea of gaining preformance. What is the best possible solution for this? How can I send commands to the queue each with unique built in data? Maybe I need to implement my own queue for commands and a single thread without io_service?

I will continue my research as I know there is a way. The idea is right cause I get preformance boost as not a single if/else statement is processed by the rendering thread :) Any help or tips will really help!

Thanks!

[image]

**Update:**

After struggling for few nights I have created a very primitive model of communication between main thread and an Aux Thread. I created a class that represents a base command to be executed by aux thread:

```
class _ThreadCommand
{
public:
    _ThreadCommand() {}
    ~_ThreadCommand() {}

    virtual void _Execute() = 0;
    virtual _ThreadCommand* Clone() = 0;
};
```

These commands that are childs of this class have _Execute() function to do whatever operation needs to be done. The main thread upon rendering fills a boost::ptr_vector of these commands While aux thread keeps on checking if there are any commands to process. When commands are found it copies entire vector to it's own vector inside _AuxThread and clears the original one. Commands are then executed by calling _Execute functions on each:

```
void _AuxThread()
{
    //List of Thread commands
    boost::ptr_vector<_ThreadCommand> _cmd;

    //Infinitive loop
    while(CORE_ENGINE->isRunning())
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> _lock(_auxMutex);
        if (CORE_ENGINE->_ThreadCommands.size() > 0)
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> _auxLock(_cmdMutex);
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CORE_ENGINE->_ThreadCommands.size(); i++)
            {
                _cmd.push_back(CORE_ENGINE->_ThreadCommands[i].Clone());
            }

            //Clear commands
            CORE_ENGINE->_ThreadCommands.clear();

            //Execute Commands
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _cmd.size(); i++)
            {
                //Execute
                _cmd[i]._Execute();
            }

            //Empty _cmd
            _cmd.clear();
        }
    }

    //Notify main thread that we have finished
    CORE_ENGINE->_ShutdownCondition->notify_one();
}
```

I know that this is a really bad way to do it. Preformance is quite slower which I'm quite sure is because of all the copying and mutex locks. But at least the renderer works. You can get the idea of what I want to achieve but as I said I am very new to multithreading. What is the best solution for this scenario? Should I return back to ThreadPool system with asio::io_service? How can I feed commands to AuxThread with all values that must be sent to renderer to preform tasks in correct way?

Comment: Use std::future and you can check if future is ready and move to the next iteration instead of sleep

Comment: Ok thank you very much :) I am researching that right now. But will not this result in slower preformance considering that probably a future aproach will probably kill some tiny amount of time? My idea is that main thread keeps on preparing commands and aux thread renders them. When main threads finishes and aux thread still renders the main thread can do something else, update OpenAL audio streams for example. I will probably need a better solution but I'll give a try. Thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: hope you know therms like `lock,mutex,critical section,atomic operation`  also do not forget to use `volatile` for variables that are affected in between threads (some compilers ignores them and some are not working at all without them for example GCC for my AT32UC3 chips will do a local copy for each global variable per each thread/ISR if not specified as volatile took me a lot of time to spot that ...). I would not start with lock-less programming when you do not have enough experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a warning**. Your "slight problem" is not slight at all. It is race condition, which is undefined behavior in C++, which, in turn, implies that anything could happen, including:

- Everything renders fine
- Image flickers
- Nothing renders at all
- It crashes on the last Saturday of every month. Or working fine on your computer and crashing on everyone's else.

Seriously, do not ever rely on UB, especially when writing library/framework/game engine.

**Now about your question.**

Lets leave aside any practical benefits of your approach and fix it first.

Actually, OpenGL implementation uses something very similar under the hood. Commands are executed asynchronously by the driver thread. I recommend you to read about their implementation to get some ideas on how to improve your design.

What you need to do, is to somehow "capture" the state at the time you `post` a rendering command. Simplest possible thing - copy the `CORE_RENDERER->state` into closure and use this copy to do the rendering. If `state` is large enough, it can be costly, though.

Alternative solution (and OpenGL goes that way) is to make every change in the `state` a command also, so

```
CORE_RENDERER->state.ModelMatrix = (*it).matrix;
CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveSubmesh = (*it).submesh;
```

translates into

```
Matrix matrix = (*it).matrix;
Submesh submesh = (*it).submesh;

THREAD_POOL->service.post([&,matrix,submesh]{
    CORE_RENDERER->state.ModelMatrix = matrix;
    CORE_RENDERER->state.ActiveSubmesh = submesh;
});
```

Notice, however, that now you can't simply read `CORE_RENDERER->state.ModelMatrix` from your main thread, as it is changing in a different thread. You must first ensure that command queue is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I got you 100% but with this you can also do harm to hardware? That is very serious! Actually I have first steped into multithreading waters 3 days ago. As you say to capture the state, that is what I am trying to do. The renderer uses material/technique/pass based rendering similar to OGRE. Since one pass is used for multiple renderables I think that maybe a best way is to "capture" information about pass that is used and the geometry that is rendered and all modeling matrices. Similar to copying render state but less information :)

Comment: @Puso, the thing about hardware is [more of a joke](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), but it still can make troubles to you in a very bizarre ways, say, stop working when upgrading to a new compiler, or porting to a new platform, or running on a computer other than yours.

Comment: That actually is one of my biggest concerns about multithreading! I fear that it simply will not work on all machines without any known reason. So I need to be  careful if I want this to work. So back to the question, the best way to make this work is to store information about passes and use it for rendering? Any ideas or articles that can be of some use? :)

Comment: @Puso, read about Command Design Pattern, it could be a good start. It can solve the problem with state capturing, and also often associated with multi-threading/asynchronous execution, so sources can give you a few directions on how to do it right.